# unreal engine 5.3 how to create a zipline?

Tags: mobile, unreal-blueprint, blueprint, zipline, unreal

I need help to create a zipline in blueprints, I have created the poles (start and end), the spline ad the cable. I'm stucked because I need to create it for mobile and I don't want it to start with a key pressed,just the moment when player interact with the spline to start ziplining wherever he interact

I tried with one I watched on YouTube but it does run perfectly, it's my first time using Blueprints

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTK5M5z0ZSw

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.